# Image not displaying completely

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to display an svg image into my pdf file. Below is my xslt code:

```
<fo:block text-align="left"
          display-align="left"
          absolute-position="absolute"
          left="-1.5cm"
          top="-1cm">
  <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit"
                         width="100%"
                         content-height="50%"
                         scaling="uniform">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
         <xsl:value-of select="$src" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>
```

**Explaination:**
My xml has many images. The above code runs in a loop and displays the images one by one. But for some images with height more than the page height, the image is getting cut. So I tried giving height = 50%. But with this my image width is also reducing.

Basically what I want is the image should fit properly in the block. and bigger images should not be cut. They should fit in the block given. Please help.

Comment: What XSLT and FO processors are you working with? Also, please include a larger sample of your code (if not the entire stylesheet) so that people can actually test this.

Comment: Hi Mathias, XSLT 1.0 and FO 1.0. But I cannot put entire stylesheet in here as it is too big and the other stuffs are not relevant to my problem. The pdf file I am generating has the figure. But if I reduce the height, width also gets reduced. I have tried giving height also to 100%. In that case, the bigger images get overlapped on the footer of the pdf file and gets cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I reduce the height, width also gets reduced.

This is presumably because you have specified `scaling="uniform"` on the graphic. This will always "preserve the aspect ratio" (see the relevant part of the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#scaling)).

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit"
                     width="100%"
                     content-height="50%"
                     scaling="non-uniform">
   <!--...-->
</fo:external-graphic>
```

Comment: Hey..Thank you. That worked. I should have thought about this.:)